# Example of orbBasic Indexed User Variables

Tags: sphero-api

I'd appreciate it if an example code could be given using the Z(Y) user variables, as I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Set the Y variable to the index you want Z to return.  For example, if you wanted to access the value at index 8 you would set Y to 8 before accessing Z.

```
Y=8
```

Would cause your next access of Z to come from the value at index 8.